# Bypass Oculus Link GPU requirements in Unity/other apps

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, quest

I am a Unity developer who recently developed a game for Meta Quest 2 VR.

However, my GPU is Intel UHD Graphics 630,which doesn't meet the requirements of using Oculus Link to build my project into my Quest.

I tried to follow Youtube videos to import the APK file into Quest and then Install it using the andriod system. However there are some unexpected behaviors.

Are there any other ways to "bypass" GPU requirements of Quest Link so that I can build my project using official ways?

Answer (score 0):

You can efficiently build your app using Meta XR UPM packages and upload it directly to your headset in the 'Run Device' section of the Build Settings. To check the logs (what is necessary when debugging) you can use LogCat in a cmd.

I did it when my pc wasn't sufficiently powerfull to run Oculus Link and I managed to create and test my app without problems (that's obviously less convenient)

That's probably not the answer you expected but don't lose hope